# Не ЧПУ и SEO (влияние на раскрутку)

Tags: seo

Влияет ли сильно на раскрутку не ЧПУ-шный сайт?)

Comment: ты сам понял что спросил?

Comment: если на сайте ссылки вида site.ru/index.php?cat=1&news=2 плохо ли это влияет на раскрутку?

Answer (score 1):

Плохо ли это влияет? Нет, тут надо сравнивать.

> Например запрос: купить абонемент на поиск в гугле

site.ru/**kupit-abonement-na-poisk-v-google**

будет лучше чем

site.ru/**index.php?cat=1&news=2**

и то наверно только потому в выдаче первый будет выделяться жирным, в отличии от второго.

читай:

http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/

http://www.webeffector.ru/wiki/

Comment: Понравилась мне фраза, высказанная на Яндексе в разделе "[Качественный сайт][1]":

> Думайте о пользователях, а не о
> поисковых системах.

Коротко и ясно )) Кстати, адрес на этот раздел, если обратите внимание - без использования ЧПУ.

   [1]:http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/?id=995342

Comment: Совершенно верно)